# how to change icon into input on click inside ngFor loop

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've got situation like this

```
<td *ngFor="let timesheet of task.timesheets; let i = index" class="w-4 position-relative">
   <div class="input-group">
        <input >
        <span class="input-group-text w-30"><em class="bi bi-clock-history" (click)="addOverHrsForTimesheet(timesheet)"></em></span>
        <span class="input-group-text w-30"><em class="bi bi-chat-right"></em></span>
   </div>
</td>
```

on click on the bi-clock-history icon I would like this span to change into another input when user could put some values. The problem is that I've got like 7 td's inside one row so how can i make sure that only icon for, for example first td got changed into input and the other 6 are left as icons?

I was thinking about taking an index of the element inside the for loop but I'm not sure if it is the right way

Answer (score 0):

I would make it as a separate component:

```
<td *ngFor="let timesheet of task.timesheets; let i = index" class="w-4 position-relative">
   <input-group [timesheet]='timesheet' />
   /* You can use event emitter to pass the data to the parent component */
</td>
```

and in your sub-component move this part along with the events and styles:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <input >
     <span class="input-group-text w-30"><em class="bi bi-clock-history" (click)="addOverHrsForTimesheet(timesheet)"></em></span>
     <span class="input-group-text w-30"><em class="bi bi-chat-right"></em></span>
</div>
```

This can help you doing the event to be emitted from a separate component part.